# Is old Danish mark symbol found in Unicode?

Tags: character, unicode

In the early 19th century, the Danish currency was 1 daler (dollar) = 6 mark. 1 mark = 16 skilling (shillings).

The symbol for a mark was this:

[image]

Is this symbol available in Unicode?

**EDIT**

As promised in a comment to @Wolff, here is an example from Hans Christian Andersen's book "En digters Bazar" (from 1842). He explains that a Guilder is worth 5 Marks and 8 Shillings:

[image]

Comment: Interesting question. I have never seen that symbol in my life. One hell of a complex symbol for a basic currency!

Comment: I have never seen this symbol either. And I am from Denmark, love typography and even collected danish coins when I was a kid! Gonna have to see if I can find an example somewhere. Maybe it was mainly used in financial tables and the like and not so much on coins and in books? I am curious about why you need the symbol ...

Comment: @Wolff The symbol was used when writing amounts. The daler was, I think, simply abbreviated (Rdlr. for Rigsdaler or something), the Mark was specified with the above symbol, and the Skilling was indicated by an italic ß. I'll edit my text above to include an example from literature.

Comment: @oz1cz _Rigsdaler_ is generally abbreviated _rdl._ in current Danish orthography; _Ordbog over det danske sprog_ tells me that _rd._, _rdr._, and _rdlr._ have all been used as well previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Nordic Mark Sign is U+20BB. The example is shown here: https://unicode-table.com/en/20BB/

Your example looks like a different design, perhaps depending on the font??  Or perhaps the Danish version was different?

There are some fonts which have a glyph - but again these look like different designs. See those shown here: http://www.fontspace.com/unicode/char/20BB-nordic-mark-sign

Comment: No its the mark that is 1/6th of a daler

Comment: @joojaa You may be right, but is it the same symbol perhaps, but only with a different design? Or was the Danish mark different from the Nordic one? Were there different ways to write it perhaps that differed by country?  Take for example the British pound "£" symbol often written or shown in old documents as ₤, or L (for Libra), there are many ways to write it, and many designs, but they were all ultimately versions of the same symbol

Comment: @BillyKerr, the discription in the Unicode standard does indeed say "early representation of the Mark currency used in Denmark and Norway", but I've never seen the symbol in the Unicode standard in actual use. However, as you point out, there could easily have been many different designs.

Comment: @oz1cz - OK, so looks like your main problem is going to be trying to find a font with that particular glyph.  If you really want to use it, perhaps consider using a graphic instead, such as an SVG.  Here's one I made using Inkscape just by auto tracing - if you want it feel free to use it http://www.filedropper.com/danishmark

Answer (score 2):

The character is encoded in the private use area of the Medieval Unicode Font Initiative (MUFI) as 
`*U+F2F1 OLD FOURISH MARK SIGN` (see [the MUFI Character recomendation v4.0](https://bora.uib.no/bora-xmlui/handle/1956/10699), pore specifically  [p.115  of this pdf](https://bora.uib.no/bora-xmlui/bitstream/handle/1956/10699/MUFI-CodeChart-4-0.pdf?page=115)). Note that this is private use character, so it can appear very differently on different fonts, you need a [font which follows a recent version of the MUFI recommendation](https://mufi.info/m.php?p=mufi&i=960). This character  is encoded in [Junicode](https://junicode.sourceforge.io/).

Note that MUFI also has a similar sign (with one flourish less) encoded just before,  `*U+F2F0 OLD MARK SIGN` and the specification discusses the possible unification with the Unicode character ₻ `U+20BB NORDIC MARK SIGN` discussed by @BillyKerr in their answer.

Given the time previous encoding in Unicode of MUFI characters took, is that any progress towards the coding of these character(s) in Unicode will take several years.

Comment: that is a great find!

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!